Groupby and Aggregate Analytics
I am trying to create aggregate anaytics based on a df. Here is a demo of my data.
input=pd.DataFrame({'ID':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C'],
              'Year':[2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001,2001],
               'Item':['a1','a2','a3','a4','b1','b2','b3','b4','c1','c2','c3','c4'],
                'Price':[1,3,4,5,2,4,7,3,5,7,6,1],
                'Label 1':[1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1],
                'Label 2':[0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1]})

My output looks like following output. My goal is for each ID and Year, I count eachLabel that is equal to 1. In addition, I also want to calculate the total price. For example, for company A, item 'a1' and 'a2' have 'Label 1' of 1, so the 'Label 1 Count'=2. The 'Label 1 Price' is 11+13=4.
output=pd.DataFrame({'ID':['A','B','C'],
              'Year':[2000,2000,2001],
               'Label 1 Count':[2,3,1],
             'Label 2 Count':[2,2,2],
             'Label 1 Total Price':[4,13,1],
             'Label 2 Total Price':[7,11,6],
              'Item Total':[4,4,4]})

What I have done is:
input['Label 1 Price']=input['Label 1']*input['Price']
input['Label 2 Price']=input['Label 2']*input['Price']

input.groupby(['ID','Year']).agg({'Label 1':'sum',
                                  'Label 2':'sum',
                                  'Label 1 Price':'sum',
                                  'Label 2 Price':'sum',
                                  'Item':'count'})

Is there a more elegant solution? Also, my raw dataset has way more "Label", so I don't want to manually create "Label x Price".

You could use filter to automatically identify columns starting with "Label". So, you could try something like:
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
input = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C'],
                      'Year':[2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001,2001],
                      'Item':['a1','a2','a3','a4','b1','b2','b3','b4','c1','c2','c3','c4'],
                      'Price':[1,3,4,5,2,4,7,3,5,7,6,1],
                      'Label 1':[1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1],
                      'Label 2':[0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1]})

Identify the columns dynamically:
label_cols = input.filter(like='Label').columns

Create the price columns dynamically:
for col in label_cols:
    input[col + ' Price'] = input[col] * input['Price']

Finally, use the agg function. The agg function handles both the sum of label counts and the sum of prices dynamically, without needing to manually write out each column name. Aggregate the data and print output:
output = input.groupby(['ID', 'Year']).agg(
    {col: 'sum' for col in label_cols} |  # Sum of Label counts
    {col + ' Price': 'sum' for col in label_cols} |  # Sum of Label prices
    {'Price': 'sum', 'Item': 'count'}  # Total Price and Item count
).rename(columns={'Item': 'Item Total', 'Price': 'Total Price'}).reset_index()

print(output)

Hope this helps!
